# How to get accurate GPS Coordinates Android LocationServices

Tags: android, gps, location-services

I am just trying to figure out what can I do to ensure I get precise GPS Coordinates from the mobile device. When I add the distances together, I get a crazy reading that I have gone 8m when the phone has not moved from my table. I do not know if it is because of the way I have set up my LocationRequest. I was reading on google something about GPS coordinates being 68% accurate, and some readings may fall out of the 68%... perhaps I should do something to remove the inaccurate readings??

Here is the location request I have created, so I can receive the location updates:

```
    private void createLocationRequest() {
        locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        locationRequest.setInterval(5000);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(2000);
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

//Some other code below which checks location settings
}
```

This is my onLocationChanged... this is where I get updates of the new location, and then calculate the distance between the two points:

```
  @Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    //For the first location update, we will assume this is the starting point
    if (currentLocation == null) {
        currentLocation = location;
    }
    float distance = 0L;
    double height = 0;
    double speed = 0;
    height = location.getAltitude();

    if (runStarted && !runPaused) {
        locationsList.add(location); //This adds the current location to the list
        runnerLocations.add(location); //This adds the current route the runner is running (without pauses)
    } else {
        locationsList.add(location);
    }

    //Calculate the distance from the last recorded gps point
    if (currentLocation != null && runStarted && !runPaused){
        distance = currentLocation.distanceTo(location);
    }
    currentLocation = location;

    //move the map view to the user's current location, regardless of their running state (paused or run)
    mapObject.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), 18));

    if (runStarted && !runPaused) {
        if (location.getSpeed() > 0) {
            speed = location.getSpeed() * 3.6;// convert m/sec to km/h
        }
        DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("###.##");
        speed = Double.valueOf(format.format(speed));
        recordedSpeeds.add(speed);
        totalDistance = totalDistance + distance;
        updateUI(speed, location, distance);
        if (height > 0) {
            height = Double.valueOf(format.format(height));
        }
        calculateCurrentCaloriesBurnt(height, speed);
    }
}
```

I was thinking of calculating the distances manually, with some formula. What else can I try, to get accurate distance calculations?

Comment: "the phone has not moved from my table" GPS can't get accurate measurements from inside buildings. To have an accurate position, you have to go outside. Also the `Location` object has an accuracy, value that u can check to better process ur logic.

Comment: "I get a crazy reading that I have gone 8m when the phone has not moved from my table" -- that is not especially "crazy". That is well within the error range of a GPS reading.